# How to make selectbox unclickable after being disable with chosen plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this selectbox and after being disable its still clickable.

Im using chosen jquery plugin in my selectbox.

My problem is after being disable the selectbox is clickable. I want to remove the clickable thing after being disable.

testing link: http://jsfiddle.net/orlando/PrHDH/

**jQuery code:**

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen();

$(".disable-chosen").on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".chosen-select").attr("disabled", "disabled").trigger("chosen:updated");
    $(".disable-chosen").off('click');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to the outline that comes up even after making it disabled, you can avoid the outline from coming up after the select has been disabled by adding the below CSS.

```
.chosen-disabled .chosen-single:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PrHDH/69/)

**Explanation:** The reason is because your select is being coverted into a `div` (by your plugin) and the outline belongs to the `a` (anchor) element with class as `chosen-single` inside it. Effectively what we are doing is instructing the browser to make the `outline` as `none` when the `chosen-disabled` class is applied to that container `div` (generated by the plugin).

**For better understanding:** (this is what is produced effectively as output by plugin)

```
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-with-drop chosen-container-active" style="width: 350px;" title="">
    <a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1"> <!-- This is the one -->
        <span>Sloth Bear</span><div><b></b></div>
    </a>
    <div class="chosen-drop">
        <div class="chosen-search">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <ul class="chosen-results">
            <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">American Black Bear</li>
            <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">Asiatic Black Bear</li>
            <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="3">Brown Bear</li>
            <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="4">Giant Panda</li>
            <li class="active-result result-selected highlighted" style="" data-option-array-index="5">Sloth Bear</li>
            <li class="disabled-result" style="" data-option-array-index="6">Sun Bear</li>
            <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="7">Polar Bear</li>
            <li class="disabled-result" style="" data-option-array-index="8">Spectacled Bear</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```